# Twitter Bootstrap with tiles centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating an app using bootstrap which house tile like style. I am new to this web designing and I bit struggling to get these tiles arranged. My requirement is, I would like to place 4 tiles inside a carousel such that each slide should contain 4 tiles.

I tried using col-cm-6 to divide the container equally. But tile stays to left aligned.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Sample tiles using bootstrap classes</h1>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive danger" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am missing.

Regards,
Raaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use`text-center`

## [DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/urvs7334/4/) demo [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/urvs7334/4/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="container text-center">
            <h1>Sample tiles using bootstrap classes</h1>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive danger" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <a href="#" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/250x250" class="thumbnail img-responsive" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It's not working in Chrome :(. It aligns only the header text.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. One more help, how do I remove the space between the tiles. There is a left and right margin

Comment: between the tiles?i just see one `h1` and `imgs` there are no titles only images

Comment: There is a left and right margin space between the tiles.

Comment: Sorry i don't know what you mean by `titles` maybe `thumbnail`? maybe this? http://jsfiddle.net/urvs7334/6/embedded/result/

Comment: Sorry, typo error. That is what exactly I am looking for. Thanks